# Optimization function of the Hodges-Lehmann location estimator

Tags: estimators, median, robust

The median minimizes the sum of absolute differences while the mean minimizes the sum of square distances. What is the function which is minimized by the Hodges-Lehmann location estimator?

Answer (score 1):

It’s the value of $\Delta$ that minimizes the absolute value of the signed rank statistic W applied to the data after subtracting that $\Delta$. In fact, W becomes 0 after subtracting the HL estimate.

To put the same concept in other words: rank the distances from this center, the sum of the ranks on the left and the sum on the right are as equal as possible.

Comment: Would you please elaborate or send me to the proper reference? I am failing to follow you

Comment: It's the definition of the HL estimate. I would recommend the book by Hollander and Wolfe. Nonparametric statistical methods. 2nd ed. John Wiley.

Comment: Thanks, Just started it